# Do you know any paper that discuss the effect of the deterrence of fines of individuals' behaviours? What is the difference between a fine a fee?

Tags: reference-request, consumer-theory, behavioral-economics

According to *Gneezy and Rustichini* the presence of an extrinsic reward in activities with a level of **intrinsic motivation** (e.g. volunteering) reduces intrinsic motivation, thus it may determine opposite results from the expected.

I wonder whether there is any research about **the effect a price may have in crowding out intrinsic motivation compared to a fine**. *Michael Sandel* faces this topic in *"the moral limits of market"*, however he does not provide any empirical evidence. Do you know any **research** that can be used to support this thesis?